# What is the requirement to meet "play a match"

Tags: achievements, pubg-battlegrounds

In PUBG there are survival rewards; one of which is "Play X matches"
I have played several games where I've definitely played and died (relatively quickly) but not got any recognition from the game for this.

What is the trigger for "Play X matches" that will give me a checkmark, so to speak, towards this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out; the requirement for getting any achievement is surviving two minutes (as well as the achievement!) for "play a match" you need to survive five minutes.

Comment: This is hidden on the "i" popup above the list of weekly achievements (it's new there)